# Setting the cell's background color with a custom function (script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to set a background color for a cell based on a color code stored in another cell.

I wrote a following google script to implement this:

```
function colorCode2Background(code) {
  if (typeof code != 'string') {
  return null;
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  // Returns the active cell
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  return cell.setBackground(code);
}
```

The problem is that when I set the cell's formula to `=colorCode2background(%CELL_NUMBER%)` where cell's value is a color code (i.e. `#ff00ff`), I get an error: "You have no permission to call function setBackground (line 12)", although I granted all the permissions to my script.

Answer (score 1):

Every custom function must return a value to display. That is not the case in your function.